# Debugging Core Data __NSCFSet addObject nil exception

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, method-swizzling, swizzle

I'm getting exceptions thrown during my unit tests, on a Core Data thread with this message:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00683a14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02334e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0068393d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x005595b9 -[__NSCFSet addObject:] + 185
    4   CoreData                            0x001d47c0 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processPendingInsertions:withDeletions:withUpdates:] + 560
    5   CoreData                            0x001cee8a -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2410
    6   CoreData                            0x001ce506 -[NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges] + 54
    7   CoreData                            0x001f359b developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 443
```

I'm trying to determine what's causing it, but since it's occurring on an `NSManagedObjectContext` queue, the thread has no stack trace with any of my own code.

I set symbolic breakpoints on `-[__NSCFSet addObject:]` and `-[NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges]`, but wasn't able to see any state while stopped there, helping me determine which objects are causing issues.

The next step that occurred to me was to try swizzling `-[__NSCFSet addObject:]` to add my own implementation, so I could stop only when the argument is nil. Hopefully the set isn't empty, and I could get more information by seeing its contents before inserting nil. I ran into difficulties swizzling it, though, since it's a private class.

Using an approach above, or one I hadn't considered, how can I get more information on what's causing the exception?

Comment: Looks like concurrency problem. Add an `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` argument to your project scheme.

Comment: @bteapot That was exactly what I needed. If you could give a more expanded answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks to @bteapot for suggesting I add the `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` argument to my scheme. I got more information on how this works from Ole Begemann's excellent [Core Data Concurrency Debugging](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/) article.

Adding this flag causes an exception to be thrown as soon as your code calls into your `NSManagedObjectContext` from an incorrect thread. This works great in Xcode, but be advised that in an Xcode Bot, this causes tests to fail with this unhelpful message:

> Lost connection to test manager service

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Comment: I normally refrain from writing thanks and the like but the up vote is not enough for this scheme argument... You and @bteapot are stars...

Comment: @Dov: What was the actual issue? Using the wrong context vs. thread combination?

Comment: @shallowThought Yes, that's exactly it

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and struggled with it all day today. Adding the concurrency debugging was a step in the right direction for me but the underlying issue was that I was attempting to access the same instance of a managed object context from different threads. The method causing my crash was trying to return a fetched object. I was able to fix it by wrapping my do, try, catch block in a context.perform block and make the method take an escaping closure as a parameter instead of returning the object.

```
func fetchUser(id: Int, completion: @escaping (User) -> ()) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %d", id)
    let request: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = predicate
    context.perform {
        // try to fetch user from core data
        do {
            if let user = try self.context.fetch(request).first {
                completion(user)
            } else {
                // if no user exists with that id, create and return a new user
                self.seedAutoPopulatingLists(for: id)
                completion(NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "User", into: self.context) as! User)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch: \(error) \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps anyone running into this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In swift 5

Create Persistence container

```
private final class PersistanceContainerProvider  {
    var container: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Test")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { storeDescription, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unable to load persistance store")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
}
```

Created ManagedContext with background concurrency

```
private init(persistentContainerProvider: DefaultPersistanceContainerProvider = PersistanceContainerProvider()){
        self.persistentContainer = persistentContainerProvider.container
        self.managedObjectContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
        print("Wasim \(self.managedObjectContext.concurrencyType.rawValue)")
    }
```

Apply managedObjectContext.performAndWait

```
func addTargetCode(symbol: Symbol) {
        managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
        do {
            if let existing = try managedObjectContext.fetch(ManagedTargetCurrency.fetchRequest(by: symbol.code)).first {
                existing.code = symbol.code
                existing.name = symbol.name
                 try save()
            } else {
                let added = (NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: ManagedTargetCurrency.entityName, into: managedObjectContext) as? ManagedTargetCurrency).require(hint: "Wrong Core Data Configuration?")
                added.code = symbol.code
                added.name = symbol.name
                 try save()
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(Errors.addError(cause: error))
        }
        }
    }
```